# Which would a good way to defend from mind controlling aliens?

Tags: technology, aliens, mind-control

Earth is being invaded by an alien species which is pretty similar to humans, being basically the only difference that instead of using for war destruction by weapons, they have developed technology that can mind control any biological being unless they have certain defenses against that, be it showing some images that can make them lose their will and embed some command, or sounds, or substances that can either breathed, ingested, or absorbed via skin (this isn't very realistic, but well, we can consider that) for the same effect. Indeed in weapon destruction abilities they are the same as a prehistoric human, as their enviroment made it extremely preferable that method of mind control instead of destruction.

My guess is that the best method would be to spy then with a drone or something and take all characterictics that would allow to identify them and then programming missiles or nuclear bombs or whatever that would identify their patterns, but maybe current techonology is still far from being able to do that.

Would this method be good to defend from them? And which other methods would be good as a defense against them?

PD: Per request I'm interested about killing them, that would be the defense, so the question could be redone as:

"Which would be a good way to kill an enemy which is already extremely risky for a human to be near it, even to see it (even if watching it via a camera)?"

PD: Edit due to Cadence request.

The mind control cannot be fought, although can be undone if the mind controlled human is captured and gets a brain operation, but this is still to be discovered  how to be done by experimenting on mind controlled humans.

They don't need to be aware of humans, as long as they use the mind control in whatever situation method any human would be mind controlled if he is reached by the mind control method.

As  I told, the can control any biological being (which has a brain) by adjusting these methods as needed, their weak point is that they are "physically weak", for example a robot with an armor and a sword could get rid of a lot of them, if would be like a caveman fighting against a medieval warrior.

Also, technologically speaking the story is set in present, whatever we have at our disposal now.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83127/discussion-on-question-by-user2638180-which-would-a-good-way-to-defend-from-mind).

Answer (score 5):

## Some humans are already immune

Since the mind-control is sensory-based (images, sounds, smells), folks with the condition [synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia) would be rather resistant and perhaps completely immune.

While there is a small resistant or immune population, few folks with synesthesia can function in a normal human-on-human military force. Years of recruiting and training and adapting will be needed before an offensive military force is ready to fight...years during which the mind-control aliens consolidate their hold on power and order their human slaves to search out any resistance.

This leads to a hilarious guerilla scenario, somewhat-inept resistance fighters bombing police stations and schools and shops with LSD and other psychoactive drugs to (temporarily) break the aliens' hold. Dudes in their  parents' basements smoking weed all day suddenly become a dull-witted resistance column with the munchies. The resistance slowly spreads and locates key targets for real (inept or drugged-out) violent attacks.

Answer (score 4):

**We get the heck out of Dodge, and send in the drones.**

I think you've more or less answered your own question already, but maybe not to the full extend.

Remember when we prohibited autonomous kill/no kill decision making in drones? We did that not because we couldn't make drones that make this decision by themselves, but because we were afraid of the consequences when they did. Guess what laws are being repealed faster than you can say "I've never seen congress come to an agreement this quick"?

Also, since we need to prove to these aliens that warfare is in fact our forte, not theirs, we are going to use their tactics against them. As they passively project their mind controlling technology everywhere they go, they might as well walk around with radio beacons signalling "Alien here, please kill me", which of course we will. If we have to equip drones with live humans in cages to act as a canary to detect mind control, so be it. Naturally we will use humans of opposing factions for this, killing two birds with one drone.

Lastly, since physical destruction is alien (pun intended) to them, let us introduce them to it. We will start easy with the trusty old minigun and rocket propelled grenade, as an overture leading to the main course of tomahawks, moabs and napalm. By the time we serve up our atomic dessert these aliens will probably be half way to alpha centauri already. Leading your old uncle to say: "You kids with your puny aliens, back in my day we had to fight the Vietcong. Now thát was an enemy!"

Comment: Good answer, although I don't understand the humans in cages idea. Is that to detect the aliens? If it is, you can just shoot at wherever the alien signal comes from until it stops.

Comment: @JohnLocke yes, it wasn't clear to me if this mind control is detectable directly, but since it is operable, I reckoned the effect on a human must be detectable. So humans could be used as the 'canary in the coal mine'.

Comment: The OP suggested that the aliens use the abilities passively, although they might not use all of the methods. So they probably can't help sending out some kind of signal. Even if they only use images, you could train a visual AI to detect mind control pictures.

Comment: @JohnLocke Perhaps, but I saw an opportunity to introduce a drone with helpless human captives attached to it, so I took it :) The premise of my answer would be that an alien race that has evolved away from physical warfare and uses a 'civilized' mind control method to subdue other species would be somewhat taken aback by human tactics and the lengths we as a species will go to destroy our enemies physically. If you want to fight humans, a civilized approach might not get you very far :)

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume what you want to achieve is a way to remove aliens without having any direct or indirect human contact as that would lead to the mind control.

I see here two problems:

1. Recognise and localise the enemy

This is the difficult part here. There are few problems here.

- How can we distinguish them? Are they similar in terms of biology but look different (e.g. have spiky ears or look totally different) or they are similar to human and cannot be distinguished easily?
- Where are they? Did they already penetrate the Earth or are they just a threat out there in the space (e.g. a space ship coming where contact tries lead to a mind control of those who tried)?

If the threat is from a spaceship and we can locate it (and we do actually) then all you have to do is set a trajectory and fire projectiles/missiles on it. Boom. Distinguishing them from humans isn't a problem in this case.

If they are already on Earth but concentrated in some way you need to locate them using some automated systems (e.g. spy drones making stills - a still should not be capable of controlling the human brain) or simply by recognising where the mind-control has a epicentre. Again, clear area from potential casualties and fire anything that can keep a trajectory. Boom.

If they are spread, you need to learn recognising them. Use machine deep learning to recognise patterns where the epidemic mental controls appear and learn how to distinguish aliens from humans. I'm assuming it is difficult in some way as otherwise you'd just capture them on stills and recognise easily. Then Use AI controlled killing drones (yes, they exist already) to make precise attacks.

---

Don't want to spoil the fun but the whole plot sounds a bit unrealistic. If they have to adapt to a species, they need to be aware which species to adapt to. So there is no way of making it automatically without spotting the human in the first place. But I have hand-waved this for the purpose of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm clarifying your points: they can be distinguished but  that needs to be done from not too much distance, their difference grade would be similar than the one from a human to an orc, they came massively to different points of the earth in a spaceship in zones were if even air control is performed they wouldn't be on time to stop them before reaching ground, they already infiltrated Earth on the past and captured some species from it to experiment and adapt their tools, so they know humans are the ones to be beaten in order to conquer the planet.

Comment: Then autonomous killing machines as described here will probably be the best solution. Plus the zones infested strongly can be destroyed with a use of some mass-destruction warfare (nuclear, chemical). Don't worry about casualties here, Humanity is at stake here.